# Allow users to input dashes to numeric field but then automatically delete dashes

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a numeric field that I'm having some problems with. Users will be inputting a 6 digit number formatted as ##-####, but since it's a numeric field, they can't enter the dash. (unless there's a blindingly obvious solution I missed, which is entirely possible). I have it formatted to present with the dash, and I didn't think it would be a huge deal for users to just not input the dash, but my testers tell me it's very off putting to be reading a number with a dash and then not enter in a dash. I tried using an input mask, but I don't like how when you enter the control it doesn't automatically start at the beginning of the field.

Is there a way to allow the user to enter dashes into the control, and then in the before update event, it deletes all the dashes? I have a bunch of data validation for what ranges of numbers are acceptable, so I don't think I can convert it to a string field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a combination of InputMask, Format, and code-behind as shown here for entering a time:

[Entering 24-hour time with input mask and full validation](http://rdsrc.us/6jPOJs)

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation](http://rdsrc.us/KAQCL9)

You should be able to modify the examples to fit your need.

Comment: yes, I switched it up a little so that if the value had previously been null, it would automatically take them to the first digit in the string. This worked great, thank you!